# Combine pandas DataFrame such that NaNs are overwritten

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames that both have missing values (`NaN`s) and contain data with the other's missing values. I would like to combine them such that the missing values are filled in from the other DataFrame. Here's an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'color': {1: 'b'}}).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'height': {0: 2}}).T
df12 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'color': {0:'w'}}).T
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'height': {1: 4}}).T
df34 = pd.concat([df3, df4])
```

Now I would like to combine `df12` with `df34` in a way that there are no missing values. But if I do `pd.concat([df12, df34])`, I get a DataFrame where each row is repeated twice, once with the value and once with `NaN`. I would like to get a DataFrame with each row not repeated and the values filled in. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want `df12.combine_first(df34)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'color': {1: 'b'}}).T
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'height': {0: 2}}).T
df12 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'color': {0:'w'}}).T
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'height': {1: 4}}).T
df34 = pd.concat([df3, df4])

df12.combine_first(df34)
```

Output:

```
0   1
color   w   b
height  2.0 4.0
```